# Error when trying to install TeamViewer

Tags: apt, 18.04, software-installation, dpkg, teamviewer

I am using Ubuntu 18.04. I am trying to install Team Viewer from Ubuntu Software, but it fails after completing the installation. I also tried to install it from the terminal, but it shows this error:

```
dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

After running the above command it gives this error:

```
dpkg: error: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/status' near line 33476 package 'libgnome-desktop-3-17:amd64':
 'Depends' field, invalid package name 'libgtk%3-0': character '%' not allowed (only letters, digits and characters '-+._')
```

On one PC all the installation steps succeeded, but I can't find the application anywhere, and on another PC it's stuck only on a dpkg error.

[image: Terminal Image]

Comment: Looks like problem is with the installation and not with with downloading. Please do not post pictures of text. Copy/paste the text instead.

Comment: Ya got it.. but is there any solution.. I cant get rid of it.. even i dnt understand what's the problem

Comment: Apparently, it doesn't like the `%` character in `/var/lib/dpkg/status`. Looks like reading picture text is not fun for you either. Anyway, I'd try to edit the file and remove the offending character.

Comment: i said got it for not to post text picture.. yes I tried to remove % character from file.. but doesn't help..

Comment: Ah, I thought you 'got it' about the picture text. Clearly that wasn't the case. Have you succeeded in removing the %? Have you checked it's not there? Is it the same error now?